# Get only unique records

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get sessions where users have only one. Users have applications which in turn have many sessions.

This is my query

```
$oneTimeSessions = DB::table('online_counselling_applications')
          ->join('online_counselling_sessions', function ($join) {
              $join->on('online_counselling_applications.id', '=', 'online_counselling_sessions.online_counselling_id')
            })->groupBy('online_counselling_id')->distinct()->get();
```

Currently I'm getting all sessions, and if there is a duplicate only one is showing. If there is a duplicate I want none to show. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `havingRaw('count(online_counselling_id)', 1);` function. 
I am not sure if this exact example will work, but take a look at the `having` or `havingRaw` function.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to remove group by and need to add distinct.

```
$oneTimeSessions = DB::table('online_counselling_applications')
          ->join('online_counselling_sessions', function ($join) {
              $join->on('online_counselling_applications.id', '=', 'online_counselling_sessions.online_counselling_id')
            })->distinct('online_counselling_id')->get();
```

I think this will help you.